# How to use json array in ajax ? (java)

Tags: java, jquery, json, ajax, servlets

I have a servlet which returns json data like :

```
{"type1":"value1","type2":"value2"}{"type1":"value3","type2":"value4"}
```

and then I want get this data to draw a table inside html, using ajax:

```
function showTable() {

    $.ajax('../json', {
        method: 'GET',
        success: function (users) {
            var result = "<tr>" +
                "<th>type1</th>" +
                "<th>type2</th>" +
                "</tr>";
                for (var i = 0; i < users.length; i++) {
                result += "<tr>" +
                    "<td>"+users[i].type1+"</td>" +
                    "<td>"+users[i].type2+"</td>" +
                    "</tr>";
            }
            var table = document.getElementById("showtable");
            table.innerHTML(result);
        }
    });
}
```

But nothing happens.

Servlet:

```
public class JsonController extends HttpServlet {
    @Override
    protected void doGet(HttpServletRequest req, HttpServletResponse resp) throws ServletException, IOException {
        resp.setContentType("text/json");
        PrintWriter writer = new PrintWriter(resp.getOutputStream());
        for (Object j : DBController.getController().getUsersInJSON()) {
            writer.append(j.toString());
            writer.flush();
        }
    }
```

This is how `getUsersInJson()` looks like. It takes data from some `ArrayList<User>` array and returns JSONArray :

```
public JSONArray getUsersInJSON() {
        JSONArray array = new JSONArray();
        for (User user : DBController.getController().get()) {
            JSONObject jUser = new JSONObject();
            jUser.put("name", user.getName());
            jUser.put("login", user.getLogin());
            jUser.put("email", user.getEmail());
            jUser.put("role", user.getRole().getName());
            jUser.put("country", user.getCountry());
            jUser.put("city", user.getCity());
            array.put(jUser);
        }
        return array;
    }
```

That is going wrong?

Comment: That is not a JSON array. It's not valid JSON at all.

Comment: `"<tr>" +
                    "<td>+users[i].type1+</td>" +
                    "<td>+users[i].type2+</td>" +
                    "</tr>";` you forget to quote.

Answer (score 2):

You are doing wrong, you have included the variable in quotes so value is not substituted. Do it this way:

```
$.ajax('../json', {
        method: 'GET',
        success: function (users) {
            var result = "<tr>" +
                "<th>type1</th>" +
                "<th>type2</th>" +
                "</tr>";
                for (var i = 0; i < users.length; i++) {
                result += "<tr>" +
                    "<td>"+users[i].type1+"</td>" +
                    "<td>"+users[i].type2+"</td>" +
                    "</tr>";
            }
            var table = document.getElementById("showtable");
            table.innerHTML(result);
        }
    });
```

Comment: Fixed that. Still nothing works.

Comment: Try console.log(users) if you are able to see the output in your script function.

Comment: I've tried console.log(users), console.log(users.length), nothing happens, output is empty. But console.log('1') typed "1".

Comment: Than this might have something to do with your java code. Try printing your array in Java before returning it, if it prints the contents

Comment: It prints the content like `{"type1":"value1","type2":"value2"}{"type1":"value3","type2":"value4"}`

Comment: This is not proper json array. It should print something like [{"type1":"value1","type2":"value2"}, {"type1":"value3","type2":"value4"}]

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
 $.ajax('../json', {
    method: 'GET',
    success: function (users) {
        var users = $.parseJSON(users);
        var result = "<tr>" +
            "<th>type1</th>" +
            "<th>type2</th>" +
            "</tr>";
            for (var i = 0; i < users.length; i++) {
                result += "<tr>" +
                  "<td>"+users[i].type1+"</td>" +
                  "<td>"+users[i].type2+"</td>" +
                  "</tr>";
             }
        var table = document.getElementById("showtable");
        table.innerHTML(result);
    }
});
```